# Prove equivalence ratio and find class of $B\subseteq A$ , $X \sim Y \Leftrightarrow X \cap B = Y \cap B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Prove equivalence ratio and find class of $B\subseteq A$ , $X \sim Y \Leftrightarrow X \cap B = Y \cap B$.

Well, I've proved really easily that it is reflexsive, symmetrical and transitive.

But I'm really struggling to find the equivalence class.

**Find: Equivalence class of** $\{1,2,3\}$, Given $A = \{1,2,3,4\} , B = \{1,2,4\}$.

I do know the fundamentals and how to find equivalence classes of 'easier' problems, but I really got confused on this one. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**note:** I started by saying $B \in P(A)$ and $a = \{1,2,3\}$, I want to find $[a]_{\sim}$

and I also do know that if $a \in P(A)$ then $[a]_{\sim} = \{ x \in P(A) | (a,x) \in \sim \}$  (And from here I'm not sure how to put 'all the pieces together' to solve it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong:

Do you want to find the equivalence class of the set $C \subseteq A$ ,given that $A\supseteq B$ and  2 sets $X,Y$ are equivalent $ \Leftrightarrow X\cap B = Y\cap B $ ?

The answer would be $[C]=\{ D \in \mathcal{P}(A) : D\cap B = C \cap B  \}$ so if $C=a$ then $ C\cap B = \{1,2 \} $ 
$[a]=\{ D\in \mathcal{P}(A) : D\cap \{1,2,4\} = \{1,2 \}  \}= \{ a,\{1,2 \} \}$

Because the condition implies that 1 and 2 must be in $D$; if $4\in D$ then the condition doesn't hold so it leaves only those sets

EDIT: Just a comment, usually sets are in Capital Letters , unlike $a$ !

Comment: I believe your answer is correct, I'm still struggling with the definition of equivalence class. Thank you! I'll review the answer until I understand it :)

Comment: with THIS definition of equivalence class, of with the concept of eq class in general?

Comment: This especially. and in general too. :(

Comment: For this case,(let me change $a$ and put $C$ you have ,by definition, $$D\in [C] \Leftrightarrow (C,D)\in \sim \Leftrightarrow C \sim D \Leftrightarrow C\cap B = D\cap B  \equiv  \{1,2,3\}\cap \{1,2\} = D\cap \{1,2\}  $$ 
Briefly

$$D\in [C] \Leftrightarrow  \{1,2,3\}\cap \{1,2\} = D\cap \{1,2\} $$
$$D\in [C] \Leftrightarrow  \{1,2\} = D\cap \{1,2\} $$
And then you have the answer I gave you above...

Comment: And in general, you can think -informally speaking- of the relation $\sim $ as what tells you which elements are "connected" by the "bridge" $\sim $ 
If the elements where you have the relation were islands , then the class of the "island" $C$ ( what is noted $[C]$ ) would be the collection of all islands connected to $C$ by a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. The equivalence relation is defined on $P(A)$. Now, just read the definition: if $X, Y \in P(A)$, $X \sim Y$ if and only if $X \cap B = Y \cap B$.
In other words, the equivalence class of $X$ only depends on the intersection of $X$ with $B$. What are the possibilities for the set $X \cap B$?

Comment: The possibilities are $1 , 2 , 4$ ?

Comment: And when they say find $[a]_{\sim}$, I need to find $[1]_{\sim} ,[2]_{\sim}, [3]_{\sim}$? Really confused on that one :(

Comment: If $X \in P(A)$, it is just a subset of $A$, not necessarily a singleton. Actually you give yourself the example $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$. In this case $X \cap B = \{1,2\}$. I am using capital letters for subsets, to avoid confusion with elements of $A$, which seems to be the origin of your trouble.

Comment: @J.e. now that makes more sense! and now I need to find the equvilance class of $\{1,2,3\} on \{1,2\}$?

Comment: I would not phrase it like that, but I think you got it. You have to find the sets $Y$ such that $Y \cap B = \{1, 2\}$.